# SQL Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, replication

I've got two database servers. One is SQL 2000, the other 2008 R2.

The application I'm writing sits mainly on the 2008 server (and thats where all the "writing" takes place)... however it does do quite a bit of looking up on the SQL 2000 instance.

The results are just too slow when joing between the linked servers are just too slow.

The SQL 2000 DB will actually be migrated in a cpl of months... but for now I need to find a better option.

Anyone got any suggestions as to the most efficient way to replicate the tables I need.

I was thinking along the lines of the folowing options:

(a) backup and restore each night
(b) full replication from 2000 - 2008... but will I be able to use the database which is being replicated to?
(c) a sql job which refreshes the tables I need every *nn* hours

I'm guessing plenty have come across this issue so a little pointer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at setting up [transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx). I've used that technique in the past for exactly the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along those lines. Would I have access to the replicated database though, while it was being replicated?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be no problem accessing the data. If you can, schedule your replication push to run during off-hours, but I even have a reporting server that is a subscriber to a continuous replication push that runs without issue.